# How can I add a range to this jQuery pagination?

Tags: jquery

I am using this jQuery table pagination script and I like to add a range instead of all the page numbers.

So instead of `[1][2][3][4][5][6][7]`
i like something `[1][2][3][>][last]`

```
function paginateIt() {
$("#pagination-ajax").remove();
  $('table#overviewJobs').each(function() {

    var currentPage = 0;
    var numPerPage = 7;
    var $table = $(this);

    $table.bind('repaginate', function() {

        $table.find('tbody tr').show()

                .slice(0,currentPage * numPerPage)
                .hide()
                .end()

                .slice((currentPage + 1) * numPerPage)
                .hide()
                .end();

          });

    var numRows = $table.find('tbody tr').length;
    //alert("Num of rows "+numRows);
    var numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / numPerPage);

    var $pager = $('<div id="pagination-ajax"></div>');

    if(numRows > numPerPage) {
        for (var page = 0; page < numPages; page++) {
          $('<span class="page-number">' + (page + 1) + '</span>')
           .bind('click', {'newPage': page}, function(event) {
             currentPage = event.data['newPage'];
             //numPerPage = 7;
             $table.trigger('repaginate');
             $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
           })
           .appendTo($pager).addClass('clickable');
        }
        $pager.find('span.page-number:first').addClass('active');
        $pager.insertAfter($('#pagination-divider'));
    } //end if numRows
    //
    //$('#pagination').html(navigation_html);
    $table.trigger('repaginate');

  });
};
```

Comment: If you've gotten the answer to a question, you should accept it as such. That's part of what keeps StackOverflow going on.

Answer (score 0):

You may apply a hack. Find your desired .page-number box index, then remove using gt(), then append another .page-number box as on click it, call next page numbers to append.